# How to get different file name when import from external memory to a listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I use this script to insert a list of files stored in the external memory, inside a list view.
The script show the names of the files in alphabetical order and do not show the file extension.

```
ListView lv;
ArrayAdapter<MyFile> adapter;

public void list() {

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/folder/filesFolder/");



    File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
    ArrayList<MyFile> theNamesOfFiles = new ArrayList<MyFile>();
    for (File temp : filelist) {
        theNamesOfFiles.add(new MyFile(temp, null));
    }
    Collections.sort(theNamesOfFiles, new Comparator<MyFile>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(MyFile lhs, MyFile rhs) {
            return lhs.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.toString());
        }
    });
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyFile>(this, R.layout.list_row,theNamesOfFiles);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);



}


public class MyFile {
    File file;
    String fileName;
    Activity activity;

    public MyFile(File file,Activity activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.file = file;
        this.fileName = file.getName();
        fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  activity.getString(activity.getResources().getIdentifier(this.fileName, "string", getPackageName()));
    }
}
```

so if i have this files in my internal memory:

```
file3.mp3  
file1.mp3
file2.mp3
```

I will see this in my list view:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

But if i would like to show a different name in the listview from a string located in the string.xml, without change the name of the original files, how can i do it?

Example:

instead of have

```
file1
file2
file3
```

i would like to show:

```
black
orange
white
```

I have fixed the code you suggest, but now i get this error in the log cat if i try to run the app

```
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.downloaddeletemaps/com.example.downloaddeletemaps.MyMapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at com.example.downloaddeletemaps.MyMapsActivity$MyFile.toString(MyMapsActivity.java:196)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at com.example.downloaddeletemaps.MyMapsActivity$1.compare(MyMapsActivity.java:53)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at com.example.downloaddeletemaps.MyMapsActivity$1.compare(MyMapsActivity.java:1)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:320)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:185)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:169)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:2038)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1891)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at com.example.downloaddeletemaps.MyMapsActivity.list(MyMapsActivity.java:49)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at com.example.downloaddeletemaps.MyMapsActivity.onCreate(MyMapsActivity.java:78)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
03-28 12:00:13.048: E/AndroidRuntime(26058):    ... 11 more
```

I think i got error at this line

```
theNamesOfFiles.add(new MyFile(temp, null));
```

Seems that cannot find resource String

```
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.downloaddeletemaps/com.example.downloaddeletemaps.MyMapsActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1057)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:1149)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:332)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at com.example.downloaddeletemaps.MyMapsActivity$MyFile.toString(MyMapsActivity.java:196)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at com.example.downloaddeletemaps.MyMapsActivity$1.compare(MyMapsActivity.java:53)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at com.example.downloaddeletemaps.MyMapsActivity$1.compare(MyMapsActivity.java:1)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:320)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:185)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:169)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:2038)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1891)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at com.example.downloaddeletemaps.MyMapsActivity.list(MyMapsActivity.java:49)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at com.example.downloaddeletemaps.MyMapsActivity.onCreate(MyMapsActivity.java:78)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
03-28 13:04:24.415: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
In Strings.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="file1">black</string>
<string name="file2">orange</string>
<string name="file3">white</string>

</resources>
```

In Activity class:

```
ListView lv;
ArrayAdapter<MyFile> adapter;

public void list() {

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/folder/filesFolder/");



    File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
    ArrayList<MyFile> theNamesOfFiles = new ArrayList<MyFile>();
    for (File temp : filelist) {
        theNamesOfFiles.add(new MyFile(temp, this));
    }
    Collections.sort(theNamesOfFiles, new Comparator<MyFile>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(MyFile lhs, MyFile rhs) {

            return lhs.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.toString());
        }
    });
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyFile>(this, R.layout.list_row,theNamesOfFiles);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);



}


public class MyFile {
    File file;
    String fileName;
    Activity activity;

    public MyFile(File file,Activity activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.file = file;
        this.fileName = file.getName();
        fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  String.valueOf(activity.getString(activity.getResources().getIdentifier(this.fileName, "string", activity.getPackageName())));
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: hi, the errors are not in the log cat, i have comment where the error are in the Activity so you can see them.

Comment: it says that The constructor   MyMapsActivity.MyFile(File) is undefined.  And activity cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: Hi, i was able to fixe the code, but now i get errors if i try to run the app, i posted the log cat

Comment: Error is `theNamesOfFiles.add(new MyFile(temp, null));` Change to `theNamesOfFiles.add(new MyFile(temp, this));`

Comment: it trows Resources$NotFoundException: String

Comment: You have saved strings in the strings.xml file in the res / values ​​folder? I have also added a change in getPackageName ();

Comment: Hi, yes, strings.xml is in res/values folder. I try to edit as you suggest but it throw the same log cat error

Comment: Ok, try this: `@Override
    public String toString() {
        return  String.valueOf(activity.getString(activity.getResources().getIdentifier(this.fileName, "string", activity.getPackageName())));
    }`